# Akka Promises and PromiseActorRef

Tags: promise, akka, actor

I'm curious to learn more about Akka **Promises** but find the lack of adequate documentation most disturbing. In the v2.3.11 docs, the only reference to them that I can find is on the [Addressing page](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html) where they give a rather vague definition of `PromiseActorRef`, and on the [Futures page](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html) where they give a few code examples surrounding `Futures.promise()`. But no where (that I can find at least) do they actually dive into what a **promise** actually is, and what use cases are suited for using them. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Akka promises are just Scala promises.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#promises

`PromiseActorRef` is an implementation detail you should not concern yourself with.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan (+1) - so: (1) are `Promise`s useable in the Java API, or just the Scala API. If its useable in Java, then can you explain what I might use a promise for? And (2) Are you saying that `PromiseActorRef` is an internal class that other actors should normally *never* interact with? If not, can you explain the situation in which I would interact with a `PromiseActorRef`? Thanks again!